# Can't move object of class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I'm making a game in which I need my hero to shoot, but I can't realize why the bullets aren't moving. They appear on the stage but they stay in the place they appear and don't move. I can't find my mistake. Thanks!!

So this is the class that has to make appear and move the bullets when I press Space.

```
public class Nivel_1
{
    public var mc:MainChar = new MainChar();
    public var Ene:Enemigo = new Enemigo();
    public var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();

    public var Back:MC_Nivel_1 = new MC_Nivel_1()

    public var Spawn_Boss:Boolean =false;
    public var boss:Boss = new Boss();

    public static var balaVector:Vector.<Bullet> = new Vector.<Bullet>();

    public var disparo:Boolean = false;


    public function Nivel_1()
    {   
    }

    public function Iniciar():void
    {
        Main.escenario.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
        Main.escenario.addChild(Back);
        Ene.Init(600,630);
        mc.Init(100,150);

        Main.escenario.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, OnKeyUpLv1);
        Main.escenario.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, OnKeyDownLv1);

        trace ("start");
    }

    public function Update(e:Event = null):void
    {
        updateBala();
        mc.Update();
        Coliciones();

        if(Spawn_Boss)
        {
            boss.Update();
        }
    }

    public function OnKeyUpLv1(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch (e.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.SPACE:
                disparo = true;
                if (disparo == true) 
                {
                    var bala:Bullet = new Bullet();
                    bala.inicializar(mc.grafica.x, mc.grafica.y - mc.grafica.height/2 , mc.grafica.scaleX);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public function OnKeyDownLv1(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch (e.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.SPACE:
                disparo = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    public function Coliciones():void
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < balaVector.length ;i++)
        {               
            if(balaVector[i].grafica_1.hitTestObject(Ene.grafica))
            {
                Ene.Destroy();
                balaVector[i].Destruir();
                boss.Init(600,650);
                Spawn_Boss = true;
                break;
            }

            if(balaVector[i].grafica_1.hitTestObject(boss.grafica))
            {
                boss.Destroy();
                balaVector[i].Destruir();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(mc.grafica.hitTestObject(Ene.grafica))
            {
                mc.grafica.x = mc.grafica.x - 3;
                mc.vida --;
            }

        if(mc.grafica.hitTestObject(boss.grafica))
            {
                mc.vida -5;
            }
    }

    public function updateBala():void
    {
        for(var i:int=0;i<balaVector.length;i++)
        {
            balaVector[i].BulletUpdate();
        }
    }

    public function EndGame():void
    {
        mc.Destroy();
        Main.escenario.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
    }
}
```

And this is the class of the bullets.

```
public class Bullet
{
    public var grafica_1:MC_Bala_1;
    public var velocidad_1:int = 15;
    public var damage_1:int = 1;
    public var direccion:int = 0;

    public function Bullet()
    {
    }

    public function BulletUpdate():void
    {
        Mover();
    }

    public function inicializar(posX:int , posY:int , dir:int):void
    {
        grafica_1 = new MC_Bala_1();
        grafica_1.x = posX;
        grafica_1.y = posY;
        this.direccion = dir;
        Game.balaVector.push(this);
        Main.escenario.addChild(grafica_1);

        trace ("bala");
    }

    public function Mover():void
    {
        grafica_1.x += velocidad_1 * direccion;

        if (grafica_1.x < 0 || grafica_1.x > Main.escenario.stageWidth)
        {
            Destruir();
        }
    }

    public function Destruir():void 
    {
        if (Main.escenario.contains(grafica_1)) Main.escenario.removeChild(grafica_1);
        Game.balaVector.splice(Game.balaVector.indexOf(this),1);

        trace ("destruir bala");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'd say your `Bullet` should never know about `Main` or `Game`, and all splicing, `addChild()` and move/destroy triggers should be located in `Game` - not even in `Nivel` class instances. You should redesign your code in terms of what moves what. Bullets can easily be moved if they change `this.x` and `this.y` inside themselves, after all bullets move, collision detection phase can be started, this is `Game`'s work, it should know about bullets, player and enemies. Bullets should **not** know about where are they going unless they have a `target` - you call `bullets[i].move()` and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

your multiplying your velocity * direction, 15*0 = 0, which is why its not moving